# I want to auto click a button on the website as the extension is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

**Objective-** As the User clicks on the chrome extension on a particular page, it automatically clicks a particular button on that website page.

I have tried following methods to generate an auto click but none of them works.

I am getting the DOM in **background.js** from the **content-script.js** and running following commands (using these commands in background page for other purposes, same errors when run in the content script).

> $(html).find(".button").click();
>
> $(html).find('#button').addEventListener('click', function() {
>   alert("hello"); });
>
> button.addEventListener('click', function() {
>       alert("hello");   });

It either gave me errors, or didn't work.

Error for the first command-

> jquery.min.js:4 Refused to execute inline event handler because it
>   violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src
>   'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Either the
>   'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce
>   ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

I also tried adding this in my **manifest.json**, but no changes in error-

> "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval';
>   object-src 'self'"

Please Help me. Thanks.

Comment: `I am getting the DOM in background.js from the content-script.js and running following commands.` why? Just run that code in the content script.

Comment: Doesn't matter, same errors in the content script too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code in your background script:

```
chrome.browserAction.onclicked.addListener(tab => {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab, {code:
        `var theButton = document.querySelector("button");
         if (theButton) theButton.click();`});
});
```

When your extension's icon ([browser action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction)) is clicked, it will click on the first button of the active webpage. If you want a specific button, refine the selector in `document.querySelector` call.

Comment: Is **.click()** functional only in the content script?

Comment: It works on any page, but you need the `tabs` (or, at least `activeTab`) permission in your manifest. BTW in the documentation for [activeTab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab) you have another code sample you could use.

Answer (score 0):

For auto clicking the button you can use trigger() method of jquery which is as follows :

```
$( "#foo" ).on( "click", function() { 
alert( $( this ).text() );});
$( "#foo" ).trigger( "click" );
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Same error-
'Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.'